# How can I allow my AsyncCallback listener to function more than once?

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have this:

```
 HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");
        listener.Start();

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);



public static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hit");
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        // Call EndGetContext to complete the asynchronous operation.
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        //Obtain a response object.
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // Construct a response. 
        string responseString =  "Hello world!";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
```

And it works. Once. If you send the same request again, you'll get nothing back, and the server will not recognize any request.

What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do in order to get my listener to listen more than once?

Comment: Call `listener.BeginGetContext` in `ListenerCallback` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jus call BeginGetContext again. There are two ways to do this one is a loop where you will accept requests in parallel but you will need to control the number of concurrent calls somehow and the other is to call the method on the end of your callback code. Alternatively you can use the synchronous method in a loop.

Comment: What will happen if one request comes in after `ListenerCallback` gets hit by a previous request but before I am able to call `BeginGetContext` again? Would this second request get dropped

Comment: I can't find this clearly stated in the documentation but looking at the API and Googling around it seems that requests will be queued. You can easily test this by putting Thread.Sleep() in your request handling code and firing another request in the meantime. Also it may be worth looking at synchronous methods if you want to process 1 request at a time.